# How to Get JSON Data from PHP Script using jQuery Ajax

Tags: php, ajaxform

I am inserting data into table and encode some parameter in json i want to display it but i am confusing. why my json parameters are not display? console.log(result) display json but i want to display single parameter from json like console.log(result.message); but it give error why?

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#form_id',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var name= $("#name").val();
      var quantity= $("#quantity").val();
      var price=$("#price").val();
   
      $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: 'insert.php',
            data: {'name': name, 'quantity': quantity,'price':price},
            success: function(result){
             
              console.log(result.message);
              console.log("success");
            }
        });

    });

  });
```

insert.php

```
<?php 
$servername="localhost";
$dbname="test";
$username="root";
$password="";

try{
    $conn=new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "success";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "error".$e->getMessage();
}

$name=$_POST['name'];
$quantity=$_POST['quantity'];
$price=$_POST['price'];


$sql="insert into product (product_name,product_quantity,product_price,barcode_image) values('$name','$quantity','$price','')";
$conn->exec($sql);

$data['message']="success";
$data['status']="ok";

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: Use the browsers Debugger to look at what is returned to the javascript

Comment: You could also add `dataType: 'JSON',`

Comment: Try to add dataType: "json" under type: "post"

Comment: @digitalniweb yes i am adding still cant run

Comment: It is often easier to help if you **show us all the error message** and not just a summary

Comment: @RiggsFolly  console.log(result); gives result as success{"message":"success","status":"ok"} but i want only result as "success"

Comment: Its treating the returned data as TEXT, did you add `dataType: 'JSON',` ? After `url: 'insert.php', dataType: 'JSON',`

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes still i am not getting output

Answer (score 0):

You should set your `content-type` header in your back-end response. ([Content-Type Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type))

Add `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before `echo` line in your php code, Or add `dataType: 'JSON'` to your `ajax` argument. ([PHP header function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php))

And you should *pay attention* to **@RiggsFolly**'s comment about **sql injection**:

> Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). Even [if you are escaping
> inputs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187), its not safe! You should alway use [prepared parameterized
> statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the MYSQLI_ or PDO API's instead of concatenating
> user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: not working plz help

Comment: what is `console.log(typeof result)` output?

Comment: I tried your codes and it works for me, are you sure about your problem ?!

Comment: console.log(typeof result  ) is string

Comment: When i add `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before echo line in your php code, it works ...